# SFDC database sync with external system

Tags: integration

We have a scenario where the records from salesforce objects needs to be synced with the external system via integration.

Problem statement: When changes on formula field it is not synced.

Eg: object A is parent, Object B is a child. Created a formula field on B. Whenever changes on A it is synced with external system but we have changes on B also(formula field value changed). How do we sync object B in this scenario. Please help me anything can be done from integration side.

Comment: I do not completely understand, you want to sync the formula value that has been updated or just the entire record?

Comment: entire record want to sync with external system. If any changes on record(means lastmodifieddate chaned, sync with external system) but lastmodifieddate is not changing with respect to formula field

Comment: I would suggest creating a trigger on the field and forcing an update that way : see https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yaSIAQ